# MathJax in MediaWiki: escaped syntax is shown, console has 404 errors

Tags: javascript, latex, mediawiki, mathjax, mediawiki-extensions

I've installed `mediawiki-1.26.2` on a private server and want to display `latex` formulas in that. So I decide to use [`Extension:MathJax`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MathJax).

At first I installed a local copy of [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to render the equations (at top level of server:`/var/www/html/mediawiki-1.26.2/`). After completing the installation I tested it by visiting http://(Server)/MathJax/test, where the page tells me that "MathJax Appears to be Working!".

Then I downloaded the extension, extracted archive, renamed it to "MathJax"  and moved it to “extensions” sub directory of `mediawiki-1.26.2`. After that I created symbolic link to "mwMathJaxConfig.js" in `[local MathJax location]/config/local` which is "/var/www/html/mediawiki-1.26.2/MathJax/config/local" directory. So already there exists two files:

1. `local.js`
2. `mwMathJaxConfig.js` (symbolic link)

Then I changed the last line of "mwMathJaxConfig.js" from:

```
MathJax.Ajax.loadComplete("_SUBSTITUTE YOUR URL___/mathjax/config/local/mwMathJaxConfig.js");
```

to this:

```
MathJax.Ajax.loadComplete("http://localhost/MathJax/config/local/mwMathJaxConfig.js");
```

Because [extension page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MathJax) says: "You might need to modify mwMathJaxConfig.js file to make this work ... ".

After all of them, I tested did extension installed correctly? (wiki → special pages → version → Installed extensions part) And name of "MathJax" was there.

But when I try to show a latex in `mediawiki`, even simple terms like these:

```
We consider, for various values of $s$, the $n$-dimensional integral
:<math> \frac{f}{g} </math>
```

do not shown correctly. Results are:

```
We consider, for various values of $s$, the $n$-dimensional integral
 \[ \frac{f}{g} \]
```

You can see `:<math>` is replaced by `\[` and `</math>` by `\]`. So I guess `MathJax` is loaded but does not load correctly and problem is in about last line of `mwMathJaxConfig.js`.

Also I saved page as html and looked at to its code and only this part of code was related to `MathJax`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./PageName_files/MathJax.js"> </script>
```

Above code was not in `head` and `PageName` is the name of saved page. I think that is replaced instead of this code  which is described in [`MathJax`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190902174134/http://docs.mathjax.org:80/en/latest/start.html#linking-your-copy-of-mathjax-into-a-web-page) docs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="path-to-MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

I looked at [Third-party Extensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20190806134311/http://docs.mathjax.org:80/en/latest/options/ThirdParty.html) in MathJax docs but did not understand its meaning.

Also I checked `local.js` file in `[local MathJax location]/config/local` whose last line is:

```
MathJax.Ajax.loadComplete("[MathJax]/config/local/local.js");
```

Do I have to change the last line of that and replace another string instead of `[MathJax]`?

Comment: Does the config file enable dollar delimiters?  By default, single dollar signs are not enabled, and you must use `\(` and `\)` for in-line math.  Try double dollars and see if those work, since they are enabled by default.

Comment: @DavideCervone But I tested other types, for example `<math>...</math>` and the result was the same.

Comment: What the of input is processed (TeX, MathML, AsciiMath) and what delimiters are used are dependent on the configuration file.  You haven't shown us that, so we can't really debug that for you.  So you will have to check the `mwMathJaxConfig.js` file and your own `local.js` file to make sure they load the proper input and output jax, load the needed preprocessor extensions, and define the proper delimiters.  You should also check if MathJax is actually loaded by checking if the `MathJax` object is defined using the browser console.  That's the first thing to check.

Comment: @DavideCervone I added another example and it's result to the question. Also I looked at html code of saved page and describe that in question. Pleas see question again. Excuse me for very long question.

Comment: If you open the browser console window, are there any error messages shown there?  Like files not being able to load, for example?  Have you checked if the MathJax object has been defined by typing `MathJax` in the console input area and seeing if an object is returned?  Have you checked that the delimiters are properly defined in one of the two configuration files?  The transformation from `<math>...</math>` to `\[...\]` looks good, provided the configuration file is properly set up.

Comment: @DavideCervone OK! Thank you! I followed your guides and understand what caused the error: name of directory of local `MathJax` must be `mathjax` and not `MathJax`. Now I can see `<math> \frac{f}{g} </math>` correct. But also I see two errors in console of browser: 1- `MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full,local/mwMathJaxConfig:19 GET http://localhost/mathjax/extensions/TeX/xypic.js?V=2.7.0` 2- `MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full,local/mwMathJaxConfig:19 GET http://localhost/mathjax/extensions/fp.js?V=2.7.0 404 (Not Found)`. Do I should to solve them or they are not important?

Comment: These two files are part of a third-party extension called [XyJax](http://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax/xyjax.html) for handling commutative diagrams called xypic.  I suspect that the MediaWiki extension you installed is configured to load that, you would would need to obtain it separately from the link above.  I don't know a lot about the extension, but I think that the references are to an old version, and that both `xypic.js` and `fp.js` have been combined in later versions.  If you don't want to do commutative diagrams, you can remove them from the `mwMathJaxConfig` configuration file.

Comment: @DavideCervone Thank you for your replies. Now all errors solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which worked for Davide Cervone and hasanghaforian:

Name of directory of local MathJax must be `mathjax` and not `MathJax`, then  \frac{f}{g}  is displayed correctly.

Two errors are shown in the browser console:

- MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full,local/mwMathJax‌​Config:19 GET http://localhost/mathjax/extensions/TeX/xypic.js?V=2.7.0
- MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full,local/mwMathJax‌​Config:19 GET http://localhost/mathjax/extensions/fp.js?V=2.7.0 404 (Not Found).

These two files are part of a third-party extension called XyJax for handling commutative diagrams called xypic. I suspect that the MediaWiki extension you installed is configured to load that, you would would need to obtain it separately from the link above. I don't know a lot about the extension, but I think that the references are to an old version, and that both xypic.js and fp.js have been combined in later versions. If you don't want to do commutative diagrams, you can remove them from the mwMathJaxConfig configuration file.